# Output is just one clk cycle instead of three

Tags: verilog

I wrote this code. The output must be 3 clk cycles one when the input B is one but when I try to Test it, the output is one just for one clk cycle. I do not know how to change the code in order to get desire output.

```
module LaserTimerTopDown (

B,X,Clk,Rst);

    input B;

    output reg X;

    input Clk,Rst;

    parameter S_OFF =0, S_ON=1;

    // shared variable

    reg Cnt_Sel, Cnt_Eq_0, Cnt_Ld;

    // datapath variable

    reg [1:0] Cnt, CntNext;

    // controller variable

    reg [0:0] State, StateNext;

    // Datapath Procedures

    always @(Cnt, Cnt_Sel) begin

        if (Cnt_Sel == 1)

            CntNext <= 2'b10;

        else

            CntNext <= Cnt -1;

        Cnt_Eq_0 <= (Cnt ==0)? 1:0;
    end

    always @ (posedge Clk) begin
        if (Rst ==1)
            Cnt <= 0;
        else if (Cnt_Ld ==1)
            CntNext <= Cnt;
    end
    // Controler Procedures 
    always @(Cnt_Eq_0, B, State)begin
        case(State)
            S_OFF :begin
                X<= 0; Cnt_Sel <= 1; Cnt_Ld <= 1;
                if (B==0)
                    StateNext <= S_OFF;
                else
                    StateNext <= S_ON;
             end
             S_ON : begin
                X<= 1; Cnt_Sel <= 0; Cnt_Ld <= 1;
                if(Cnt_Eq_0 ==0)
                    StateNext <= S_ON;
                else
                    StateNext <= S_OFF;
              end  
        endcase
    end
    always @(posedge Clk) begin
        if (Rst ==1)
            State <= S_OFF;
        else
            State<= StateNext;
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: Should perhaps this line: `CntNext <= Cnt;` not be this: `Cnt <= CntNext;`? The assignments in your two combinational processes should be blocking; (`=`), not non-blocking (`<=`).

Comment: I see that Cnt_next is assigned through multiple always blocks. What's the exact logic for Cnt_next. Also you have not added Rst, in the sensitivity list of always block.

Comment: Thank you Mattew Taylor, I do all your points. It works like as I expect.

Comment: Thank you Karan Shah. When I notice to exact logic for CntNext and revise it. It works like as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
module LaserTimerTopDown (

B,X,Clk,Rst);

input B;

output reg X;

input Clk,Rst;

parameter S_OFF =0, S_ON=1;

// shared variable

reg Cnt_Sel, Cnt_Eq_0, Cnt_Ld;

// datapath variable

reg [1:0] Cnt, CntNext;

// controller variable

reg [0:0] State, StateNext;

// Datapath Procedures

always @(Cnt, Cnt_Sel) begin

    if (Cnt_Sel == 1)

        CntNext <= 2'b10;

    else

        CntNext <= Cnt -1;

    Cnt_Eq_0 <= (Cnt ==0)? 1:0;
end

always @ (posedge Clk) begin
    if (Rst ==1)
        Cnt <= 0;
    else if (Cnt_Ld ==1)
        Cnt <= CntNext;
end
// Controler Procedures 
always @(Cnt_Eq_0, B, State)begin
    case(State)
        S_OFF :begin
            X<= 0; Cnt_Sel <= 1; Cnt_Ld <= 1;
            if (B==0)
                StateNext <= S_OFF;
            else
                StateNext <= S_ON;
         end
         S_ON : begin
            X<= 1; Cnt_Sel <= 0; Cnt_Ld <= 1;
            if(Cnt_Eq_0 ==0)
                StateNext <= S_ON;
            else
                StateNext <= S_OFF;
          end  
    endcase
end
always @(posedge Clk) begin
    if (Rst ==1)
        State <= S_OFF;
    else
        State<= StateNext;
end
endmodule
```